# "With added bacon flavour and absolutely no horse meat" meaning?

Tags: meaning

So my mathematics lecturer sent the following message, and although it is not crucial I would like to know what "with added bacon flavour and absolutely no horse meat" could possibly mean? I understand that it's probably some kind of extended metaphor for "new and improved", but I have never heard the term before, and thought that some of you might have. Here is the message:

> "Dear Student,
>
> As has been pointed out to me, I made an error with regards to Assignment 2. But the good news is that Assignment 2 has been rebooted, new and improved (with added bacon flavour and absolutely no horse meat)!"

Comment: "Bacon flavor" is something that, at times, seems to be added to everything -- adding taste without any real substance.  "Horse meat" of course is the flesh of a horse, sometimes known to be (illegally) substituted for beef in cheap burger restaurants and the like.

Comment: I wish I'd had your mathematics lecturer, he sounds like a riot.

Answer (score 2):

It means nothing really, it's just a throw-a-way line intended as a joke. The horse meat bit (if you live in the UK) is likely a reference to the [Horse Meat scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_meat_adulteration_scandal), which was the news that a lot of ready meals had horse meat in them.

Comment: I live in Australia, but I figured as much. Just got a bit confused because it was just a little random.